# Run external .DLL commands with PHP on Windows localhost

Tags: php, vb.net, dll

I have a project where I need to run VB commands from PHP. It's a electric circuit board (MotorBee from PC-control) which has it's own mtb.dll file and can be programmed using VB and something like this: [LINK TO FILE HERE](http://pastebin.com/S7EWiiSW) (You can skip to line 370 where code starts)

Is there a way to send this function to mtb.dll via php (as this is actually a part that I need to send):

```
Declare Function SetMotors Lib "mtb.dll" (ByVal on1 As Integer, ByVal speed1 As Integer, ByVal on2 As Integer, ByVal speed2 As Integer, ByVal on3 As Integer, ByVal speed3 As Integer, ByVal on4 As Integer, ByVal speed4 As Integer, ByVal servo As Integer) As Boolean
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`PHP Win32 API`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.w32api.php) which allows you to invoke functions declared in Win32 libraries. And here are [`some examples`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/w32api.examples-uptime.php).